# Can I play xvid files on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, playback, xvid

I burned some xvid files on a DVD and I am hoping a friend will be able to play them back on her PS3.
I've read it's possible but that you may need to copy the files to the hard drive?
Has anyone tried it, is the copying to hard drive bit true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a PS3 and use TVersity to stream XVID video to my PS3:

http://tversity.com/support/quickstart-upnp

Comment: There is also one called PS3 Media Server.

Answer (score 1):

rather than a straight burn the data to disc, re-encode them to a format that the ps3 recognizes. [DVD Flick](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdflick/) supports the [format](http://www.dvdflick.net/features.php) and can re-encode it to be playable on a standalone DVD player.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both your surmises seem to be right. From Kotaku, as reliable a source as any: [PS3 Plays XviD, But With A Catch](http://kotaku.com/335260/ps3-plays-xvid-but-with-a-catch). The Gizmodo article it links to has some more details.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way is to use the Vuze (formally Azureus) client. If you are downloading files such as these you simply need todrag the file into the "PS3" menu bar and it will automatically convert to a suitable format for viewing on the PS3. Once you've fired up your PS3, search for the Vuze media client within the "Video" menu option and voila!
This will work with avi encapsulations and wmv formats and is a really easy way to stream media to your TV without having to worry about complicated formats and conversions.

Vuze is free from http://www.vuze.com/

Answer (score 1):

PS3 plays some xvid files. Some it will refuse to play because they don't conform to divx standards. You can convert them to divx before you burn them.

I use tversity to stream video to my ps3 and convert when nessasary so I dont have to worry about what will and will not play.